# Pi WLAN not connecting to router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to connect my Raspberry Pi Zero W to the internet using wlan, however I am having trouble connecting to the router at all. By default the Pi is assigned `169.254.94.159` and pinging the router at `192.168.0.1` is unsuccessful. I have restarted the router a couple of times to no avail, and tried to connect using a static IP. Oddly, my router's settings still list the Pi under connected devices with its old IP (when it was able to connect) at `192.168.0.58/24`.

In case it helps, my wpa_supplicant.conf contains:

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="<my ssid>"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="<my password>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

(Where  and  are my actual ssid and password).

Comment: Legit r-pi or Chinese clone?

Comment: Legit. Got it from thepihut which is listed on the rpi site

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out why the router still had the old Pi IP address but factory resetting it seems to have worked.